# Making a Variable be formatted as currency in a list box problem

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem where I'm making all the listed items in a list box be with the format currency and the third and fourth item added are not showing up as currency even though I have it laid out the same with the first second and fifth options and it works perfectly. Also I have no idea how to add text before the currency in the list box. Any help will be greatly appreciated. This is the code I have so far...

```
        Dim intCost1, intcost2, intcost3, intcost4 As Single

    'This code does the maths and breaks down the costs of the insurance so the employee can easily the cost to the customer
    lstCostBreakDown.Items.Clear()
    'This is the inital quote before any add ons or reductions
    lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(intFinalVal))
    intCost1 = (FormatCurrency(intFinalVal))
    'This is the cost of the add on 
    lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(sngAddOn * intFinalVal))
    intcost2 = (FormatCurrency(sngAddOn * intFinalVal))
    'This is the reduction you get for private health insurance 
    lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(intFinalVal * sngAddOn + intFinalVal) * sngHealthInsurance)
    intcost3 = (FormatCurrency(intFinalVal * sngAddOn + intFinalVal) * sngHealthInsurance)
    'This is the amount of VAT the customer has to pay 
    lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(intCost1 + intcost2 - intcost3) * 0.2)
    intcost4 = (FormatCurrency(intCost1 + intcost2 - intcost3) * 0.2)
    'This is the subtotal of all costs and reductions 
    lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(intCost1 + intcost2 - intcost3 + intcost4))
```

Comment: Set `Option Strict On`. Correct everything that is now squiggled and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In those 2 lines you're effectively converting the values to currency, then multiplying them which will implicitly convert them to just numeric values again.  So these two lines need to be changed.

```
lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(intFinalVal * sngAddOn + intFinalVal) * sngHealthInsurance)
lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(intCost1 + intcost2 - intcost3) * 0.2)
```

To these (note the parenthesis).  Effectively making the conversion *after* you've calculated their values.

```
lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add(FormatCurrency((intFinalVal * sngAddOn + intFinalVal) * sngHealthInsurance))
lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add(FormatCurrency(intCost1 + intcost2 - intcost3) * 0.2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works. Just wondering now if you have any idea how to add text before the figures?

Comment: It should just be lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add("Whatever text" & ... then leave the existing code after.

Comment: @SeanDolan Please thank the poster of the answer by accepting the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.