# Index out of range error making my programme crash when adding text before variables involved with maths in a list box

Tags: vb.net

The text shown in the code below is making my programme crash for no reason obvious to me, was just wondering if anyone could figure out why this is making it crash

```
    Private Sub frmReceipt_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim intCost1, intcost2, intcost3, intcost4 As Single

    'This code does the maths and breaks down the costs of the insurance so the employee can easily the cost to the customer
    lstCostBreakDown.Items.Clear()
    'This is the inital quote before any add ons or reductions
    lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add("Gross Price-"(FormatCurrency(intFinalVal)))
    intCost1 = (FormatCurrency(intFinalVal))
    'This is the cost of the add on 
    lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add("Add-Ons-"(FormatCurrency(sngAddOn * intFinalVal)))
    intcost2 = (FormatCurrency(sngAddOn * intFinalVal))
    'This is the reduction you get for private health insurance 
    lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add("Private health insurance reduction-"(FormatCurrency((intFinalVal * sngAddOn + intFinalVal) * sngHealthInsurance)))
    intcost3 = (FormatCurrency((intFinalVal * sngAddOn + intFinalVal) * sngHealthInsurance))
    'This is the amount of VAT the customer has to pay 
    lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add("VAT-"(FormatCurrency((intCost1 + intcost2 - intcost3) * 0.2)))
    intcost4 = (FormatCurrency(intCost1 + intcost2 - intcost3) * 0.2)
    'This is the subtotal of all costs and reductions 
    lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add("Subtotal"(FormatCurrency(intCost1 + intcost2 - intcost3 + intcost4)))
```

Comment: Set `Option Strict On`. Correct everything after and try again. [Reiterated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289058/making-a-variable-be-formatted-as-currency-in-a-list-box-problem#comment93460399_53289058).

Comment: Tried that and still same error and crash happening?

Comment: Since you tried that, post the code that you came up with after you corrected all the problems that did arise.

Comment: Sounds a lot like a problem with your `FormatCurrency` function. Please add that to your question. By the way - to make your code a little easier to maintain, move all the lines like `intCost1 = (FormatCurrency(intFinalVal))` up one so that they are above the lines that add stuff to a list and change THAT line to something similar to `lstCostBreakDown.Items.Add("Gross `Price-" & intCost1.ToString)
   `

Comment: Don't forget the `&`